# Which data type may I use to take 100 digits in a variable in c++

Tags: c++

[image]

On that I have to multiply two variable

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: Did you consider performing any research?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I thought that's what this is - isn't Stack Overflow the first point of entry for any kind of that "research" you oldtimers are going on about?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in data type for this much of integer length. Better go for array and place the digits at the indices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in type that can accommodate you. You will need to implement the logic yourself, or use an existing library such as [this one](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the largest type in C/C++ is long long which is at least 64 bits and I've seen no contemporary compiler with standard types longer than 64 bits. So the answer to your question is NO at this time.

Also, refer below explanation.

InfInt is simply a lightweight large integer library which consists of a header file. So, all you have to do is to include the header file provided and start using huge integers in your applications.

It is pretty straightforward to use the library. Just create an instance of InfInt class and start using it:

```
InfInt myint1 = "15432154865413186646848435184100510168404641560358";
    InfInt myint2 = 156341300544608LL;

    myint1 *= --myint2 - 3;
    std::cout << myint1 << std::endl;
```

refer this link: [click here](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/)